# Add css class to all admin form field

Tags: django

I need to assign a boostrap class to all my user's field in Django admin form, I wrote this code but it does not work.

```
  formfield_overrides = {
    models.CharField:     {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})},
    models.CharField:     {'widget': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})},
    models.DateField:     {'widget': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'})},
    models.EmailField:    {'widget': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})},
    models.BooleanField:  {'widget': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})},
 }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: [Check the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances) on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs but I am not able to bind the form to my admin page

Comment: @Mark116 To bind the form to the administrator page, you must in the admin.py to create a class that inherit the admin.ModelAdmin. Next, specify the form attribute with your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form

```py
#yourapp/forms.py
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = YourModel
        fields = (field1,field2,field3,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self._meta.fields:
            attrs = {'class':'form-control'}
            if self.fields[field].widget.__class__.__name__ == "DateTimeInput":
                attrs.update({'type':'date'})
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update(attrs)
```

Next, admin.py

```
#yourapp/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import YourForm
from .models import YourModel

class AdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = YourForm

admin.site.register(YourModel,AdminModel)
```

You can learn more from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override some of the Field options for use in the admin, please check this for detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides. And the most common use of formfield_overrides is to add a custom widget for a certain type of field.